# Unchecked cast warning when wrapping primitives for generic array

Tags: java, generics, wrapper, primitive

I'm writing a small package of sorting functions that work on an object of class `SortableArray<T extends Comparable<T>>` because I want to be able to sort primitive objects like `int`, I need to wrap the primitives in a class object, in this case specifically, `Integer`. So, I overloaded my constructor to take an array of type `int`, wrap each in an `Integer`, store it in an array, `temp`, and then point `GenList` to `temp`. I added a cast of `(T[])` to make the IDE happy, but now I have an unchecked type warning.

Here is my code:

```
 package sorts;

public class SortableArray<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T[] GenList;


    public SortableArray(T[] theList) {
        GenList = theList;
    }

    public SortableArray(int[] theList) {
        Integer[] temp = new Integer[theList.length];   
        for(int i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = new Integer(theList[i]);
        }
        GenList = (T[]) temp; //warning here
    }
}
```

Should I just suppress the warning, or is there a safer approach?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this could be problematic is if I tried to do something like this:

```
SortableArray<String> array = new SortableArray<>(new int[] { 3, 9, 9 });
```

It looks ridiculous, but it's entirely legal, and will bite you when you want to use it somewhere else.

What you may want to consider instead is a static factory method, which might look something like this:

```
public static SortableArray<Integer> createSortableArrayFromInts(int[] theList)
{
    Integer[] temp = new Integer[theList.length];   
    for(int i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = Integer.valueOf(theList[i]);
    }
    return new SortableArray<Integer>(temp);
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping to see a solution that allowed me to wrap the primitive in the constructor, but that would mean getting to have my cake and eat it too. Your answer was insightful and I'm going to use it!